# Wrong stem position in balloon-style tooltips in report list-view

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, listview, tooltip

I'd like to change the default style of the list-view control's tooltips to **balloon**.

I first called `ListView_GetToolTips()` to get the `HWND` of the list-view's tooltips control, and then  used `GetWindowLongPtr()`/`SetWindowLongPtr()` to add the `TTS_BALLOON` style.

I handle `LVN_GETINFOTIP` to customize the tooltip for the items (first column) in the list-view: the tooltip texts that appear for the first column items are actually a copy of the text of the third column. The other columns (subitems) are managed automatically by the list-view.

The balloon-style tooltips for the **first column items seem OK**; their stems are correctly positioned:

[image]

But the tooltips for the **second column seem drawn wrongly**, e.g. the balloon is drawn as if it was referred to a subitem in a row **below** the actual row pointed by the mouse cursor.
In the following picture, the "star" indicates the position in which the mouse cursor was when the tooltip appeared, but the tooltip's stem points to a row below, marked with an ellipse:

[image]

The strange thing is that the tooltips for the **third column seem drawn correctly**.

Is this a bug in the list-view control? (I'm using Windows 7.)
Or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The ListView uses a tracking tooltip and positions it to unfold and reveal the hidden text in a column that's too small. It's not expecting its tooltip to be a balloon and so doesn't compensate for that.

You'd need to sub-class the tooltip itself, watch for `TTM_TRACKPOSITION` messages from the ListView, and adjust the coordinates.

Your second question - the shaded background comes from the system theme. You should be able to get it by calling `SetWindowTheme` on the tooltip (I'm not sure why the ListView disables themes for the tip).

Comment: How is the `SetWindowTheme` API used? I mean: what string arguments should I pass to `SetWindowTheme()`? ([Its MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827(v=vs.85).aspx) is horrible!)

Comment: Actually (again) do you have a manifest in your program that enables ComCtl v6? If not, adding one of those is probably all you need.

Comment: I thought of the manifest thing before, in fact I added it and now the tooltips are properly shaded (I created an _empty_ Win32 project with Visual Studio, so the manifest was missing).